# Export to data to csv/xlsx

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, xlsx

I made a wordpress plugin with a calculator the results are getting emailed. I now have a admin page with the emails and the date time someone sent a email.

I now want these emails to be exported to a spreadsheet.

I got this code. it works but the export gives me the complete page instead of just the saved data.

```
function dew_point_emails_page_callback() {
    // Check if the current user has permission to access the admin page
    if (!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
        wp_die('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.');
    }

    // Get the saved emails from the database
    $saved_emails = get_option('dew_point_emails', array());

    // Include the admin header
    include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php';

    // Handle export button click
    if (isset($_POST['export_emails'])) {
        export_emails_to_csv($saved_emails);
    }

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Dew Point Emails</h1>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <p><input type="submit" name="export_emails" class="button button-primary" value="Export Emails"></p>
        </form>

        <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Date Submitted</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($saved_emails as $email_info) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo esc_html($email_info['email']); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo esc_html($email_info['date']); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Export emails to a CSV file
function export_emails_to_csv($emails) {
    // Set headers for CSV download
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=emails.csv');

    // Create a memory buffer
    $output = fopen('php://temp', 'w');

    // Write the BOM (Byte Order Mark) to handle UTF-8 characters properly in Excel
    fputs($output, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");

    // Write email data as HTML table
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Date Submitted</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($emails as $email_info) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html($email_info['email']); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo esc_html($email_info['date']); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
    $tableContent = ob_get_clean();

    // Write table content to CSV
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($tableContent, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $rows = $xpath->query('//table/tbody/tr');

    // Write headers
    fputcsv($output, array('Email', 'Date Submitted'));

    // Write email data
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $rowData = [];
        foreach ($row->childNodes as $cell) {
            $rowData[] = trim($cell->nodeValue);
        }
        fputcsv($output, $rowData);
    }

    // Rewind the buffer
    rewind($output);

    // Read the contents of the buffer
    $csvContent = stream_get_contents($output);

    // Close the buffer
    fclose($output);

    // Output the CSV content
    echo $csvContent;

    // Stop further execution
    exit();
}
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong and If it is even possible to export it like this.

Comment: You have not told us where you are calling `dew_point_emails_page_callback`, but it looks like that happens somewhere already within the page assembly process. Put the part that processes this into the functions.php of your theme, then it should execute before any page content generation.